# Map files getting executed by Mikro ORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, postgresql, mikro-orm

I am a beginner learning Mikro-ORM and I keep running into an issue with my `.map` files. I am compiling my `typescript` into javascript and then executing the js with node. However, when I use node to execute the javascript, I run into the following error:

```
[query] begin
[query] select * from "mikro_orm_migrations" order by "id" asc [took 31 ms]
[query] select * from "mikro_orm_migrations" order by "id" asc [took 32 ms]
== Migration20210311015910.js: migrating =======
[query] rollback
/home/runner/fullstack-tut/dist/migrations/Migration20210311015910.js.map:1
{"version":3,"file":"Migration20210311015910.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["../../src/migrations/Migration20210311015910.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":";;;;;;;;;;;;AAAA,sDAAkD;AAElD,MAAa,uBAAwB,SAAQ,sBAAS;IAE9C,EAAE;;YACN,IAAI,CAAC,MAAM,CAAC,mJAAmJ,CAAC,CAAC;QACnK,CAAC;KAAA;CAEF;AAND,0DAMC"}
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Migrator.resolve (/home/runner/fullstack-tut/node_modules/@mikro-orm/migrations/Migrator.js:141:27)
    at Object.customResolver (/home/runner/fullstack-tut/node_modules/@mikro-orm/migrations/Migrator.js:43:44)
    at Migration.migration (/home/runner/fullstack-tut/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:60:38)
    at /home/runner/fullstack-tut/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:121:37
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/runner/fullstack-tut/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:9:103)
    at _next (/home/runner/fullstack-tut/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:11:194)
    at /home/runner/fullstack-tut/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:11:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)

[query] rollback
/home/runner/fullstack-tut/dist/migrations/Migration20210311015910.js.map:1
{"version":3,"file":"Migration20210311015910.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["../../src/migrations/Migration20210311015910.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":";;;;;;;;;;;;AAAA,sDAAkD;AAElD,MAAa,uBAAwB,SAAQ,sBAAS;IAE9C,EAAE;;YACN,IAAI,CAAC,MAAM,CAAC,mJAAmJ,CAAC,CAAC;QACnK,CAAC;KAAA;CAEF;AAND,0DAMC"}
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Migrator.resolve (/home/runner/fullstack-tut/node_modules/@mikro-orm/migrations/Migrator.js:141:27)
    at Object.customResolver (/home/runner/fullstack-tut/node_modules/@mikro-orm/migrations/Migrator.js:43:44)
    at Migration.migration (/home/runner/fullstack-tut/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:60:38)
    at /home/runner/fullstack-tut/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:121:37
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/runner/fullstack-tut/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:9:103)
    at _next (/home/runner/fullstack-tut/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:11:194)
    at /home/runner/fullstack-tut/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:11:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

Currently, I have just been deleting these `map` files but I don't see this as a solution for me to continue going along. I have been searching for this issue for several hours and haven't found a question like this anywhere on StackOverflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the ORM misconfigured, this is working based on `migrations.pattern` configuration, and apparently you are overriding the defaults (`/^[\w-]+\d+\.ts$/`), to something that also allows map files.

Funny to see a question like this, while you did not share your ORM configuration (where you must have overriden quite a lot of things).

For JS files you should do something like `/^[\w-]+\d+\.js$/`. As long as you know there will never be JS and TS files next to each other (so you have sources and dist in different folders), you could also do `/^[\w-]+\d+\.[jt]s$/`.

**You are most probably missing the `$` at the end of the regexp.**

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this and I wasn't thinking about including my ORM configuration. I was following a tutorial that did in fact tell me to override the default regex. However, it worked for him, so I assume I have mistyped the regex. Thanks for the help, and I will accept if this solves my issue once I try it!

Comment: Yeah Ben Awad, right? That tutorial is full of wrong assumtions and bad advices :/ Ben did not really study the ORM first, nor asked me how to handle things, which is also the reason he decided to switch to typeorm in the middle of it I guess :D

Comment: Another nonsense is how he shows the CLI config, correct way to type it can be found here: https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/1494#issuecomment-786181874

Comment: Yes, I was following his full-stack one. Do you have any alternative tutorials which you recommend :)?

Comment: Not really, better to read the docs or check the tests (and feel free to join the slack and ask questions there). I'd like to create a tutorial for the docs at some point, maybe once v5 is out (so later this year) - also it won't be any "full stack tut", but rather a backend one aimed at the ORM only (maybe using nest too).

Comment: Thank you for all the help and guidance. For now, I think I will continue on his tutorials, and read the docs.

Comment: I wasn't missing the dollar at the end but I had missed a character in the pattern